# Proof Help/Hint: A mapping $\delta : A \rightarrow B$ is constant if and only if $\delta\alpha = \delta$ for all $\alpha : A \rightarrow A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ A mapping δ:A→B is constant if and only if δα=δ for all α:A→A.

I have already proved the theorem in the right direction, and I understand why the left implication works, I just can't get a formal proof together. If anybody could provide some hints, or just post a proof in the left direction, that would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\delta\circ\alpha=\delta$ for all $\alpha:A\to A$. Fix any $a_1,a_2\in A$. Define $\alpha:A\to A$ in the following way:
\begin{align*}
\alpha(a_1)&\equiv a_2,\\
\alpha(a_2)&\equiv a_1,\\
\alpha(a)&\equiv a\text{ for any other $a\in A\setminus\{a_1,a_2\}$.}
\end{align*}
Then, we have that $$\delta(a_1)=(\delta\circ \alpha)(a_1)=\delta(\alpha(a_1))=\delta(a_2).$$
Since this is true for any arbitrary $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $A$, we can conclude that $\delta$ returns the same value for all elements in $A$. In other words, $\delta$ is a constant function.

Comment: I'll accept this answer when it lets me. This is just what I needed. I was trying to index the elements of A in some way, I just couldn't figure out how. Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually one thing, you're defining that for a singular map $\alpha$. I need to show that the function equality works for any mapping $\alpha : A \rightarrow A$.

Comment: @AthelstanCarlton Thanks for the accept. I’m glad to have helped. When proving sufficiency (“if”), you can actually _assume_ that $\delta\circ\alpha=\delta$ for any mapping $\alpha:A\to A$, and then you can use one _particular_ $\alpha$, like in my answer, to show that $\delta$ is constant. I think what you refer to is the following: When you need to show necessity (“only if”), you first assume that $\delta$ is constant and then you need to prove that $\delta\circ\alpha=\delta$ for any $\alpha:A\to A$, indeed. But you claim to have already proved that direction.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, not sure how I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: You can simplify the chosen function $\alpha$. Let $\alpha(a) = \bar{a}$ for all $a$, for some element $\bar{a}$ of $A$.

Comment: @A.Burrell You are certainly right; that would have resulted in an even simpler solution.